# Sorting data issue

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

So I have a little issue in sorting some data I have.  In a Telerik Grid, I have a column called Requestor that displays the name of a person or Unit (group of people).  The problem is, Requestor has two sources it can get it's data from.  Here are the two sources.

1.) RequestorId: This is a foreign key to a table called Customer.  Here, I store all the data for the user, including their full name.  This field can be null btw.

2.) UnitId: This is another foreign key to a table called Units.  Here, I store all the data for the Units, particularlly their names.  This field can be null btw.

Here is the logic:

```
//Entity class that contains all the data for my grid
var purchaseOrders = _purchaseOrders.GetPurchaseOrders();

//Key is Id of PurchaseOrders, Value is name of requestor
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

foreach (var purchaseOrder in purchaseOrders)
{
if (purchaseOrder.requestorId != null)
   dictionary.add(purchaseOrder.Requestor.Fullname);
else 
   dictionary.add(purchaseOrder.unit.Fullname);
}

dictionary.orderby(x => x.value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x.Value);
var tempPurchaseOrders = new List<PurchaseOrder>();

foreach (var item in dictionary)
{
   tempPurchaseOrders.Add(purchaseOrders.Where(x => x.Id == item.Key).FirstOrDefault());
}

purchaseOrders = tempPurchaseOrders.AsQueryable();
return purchaseOrders;
```

This logic returns an ordered list based on what I want to do, however, the problem is the amount of time it takes to process.  It takes 1 minute to process.  That's horrible obviously.  Is there anyway to optimize this?  I cut down the source after I return for the grid because there is no logical way to really cut it down beforehand.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

**Edit: I found out I no longer am required to use the RequestName field.  That limits the data to two areas now.  Still a minute to process though.**

Comment: How much data are you sorting?

Comment: Currently 13.2k records.  I have more incoming once I complete my project.  Most likely another 1k or so, but still, I want to smoothing things out the best I can.

Comment: `dictionary.add` (lower case)? With one argument? What is the key? And do you know where the bottleneck is? It's not necessarily the sorting.

Comment: The bottleneck is going through all 13.2k records is my guess.  As for the dictionary, the key is purchaseOrder.Id so I know how to rebuild the purchaseOrders list when I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with my own solution.  I first tried what both Sławomir Rosiek and Gert Arnold did.  Unfortunately, like Gert mentioned, the first answer would not go through.  The second one had similar issues.

In the end, I created a class to store the data from both Requestors and Units.  It consisted of the following:

```
internal class RequestorData
{
   public int entityId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool isRequestorId { get; set; }
}
```

Next, I did the following.

```
//Entity class that contains all the data for my grid
var purchaseOrders = _purchaseOrders.GetPurchaseOrders();
var tempPurchaseOrders = new List<PurchaseOrder>();
var requestors = new List<RequestorData>();
var customers = purchaseOrders.Select(po => po.Requestor).Distinct().ToList();
var units = purchaseOrders.Select(po => po.Unit).Distinct().ToList();

foreach (var customer in customers)
{
   if (customer != null)
      requestors.Add(new RequestorData { entityId = customer.Id, Name = customer.FullName, isRequestorId = true });
}
foreach (var unit in units)
{
   if (unit != null)
     requestors.Add(new RequestorData { entityId = unit.Id, Name = unit.FullName, isRequestorId = false });
}

requestors = requestors.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList();

foreach (var requestor in requestors)
{
   var id = requestor.entityId;
   if (requestor.isRequestorId)
      tempPurchaseOrders.AddRange(purchaseOrders.Where(po => po.RequestorId == id).ToList());
   else
      tempPurchaseOrders.AddRange(purchaseOrders.Where(po => po.UnitId == id).ToList());
}

purchaseOrders = tempPurchaseOrders.AsQueryable();
return purchaseOrders;
```

I ran this new rendition and have a 5-6 second time of wait.  That's not perfect but much better than before.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this:

```
return _purchaseOrders.GetPurchaseOrders().Select(i => new 
{
     OrderColumn = i.requestorId != null ? purchaseOrder.Requestor.Fullname : purchaseOrder.unit.Fullname,
     // map other columns
})
.OrderBy(i => i.OrderColumn);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit like Sławomir Rosiek's solution (but entity framework won't accept that statement):

```
return _purchaseOrders.GetPurchaseOrders()
                      .OrderBy(o => o.unit.Fullname).ToList();
```

(since you don't use RequestName anymore).

Especially when `GetPurchaseOrders()` is an `IQueryable` from EF you delegate the sorting to the database engine because the sort expression becomes part of the SQL statement.